# how we open an android application from an html button when open in phone browser

Tags: android

i just need to open the application when i click on button of html page if html page are open in android phone browser.

sorry for my English.

please suggest.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An installed application can be launched from deep links.

See [Deep Linking](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can set `intent-filter` of `Main-activity` of your application as follow to open this application from browser.

```
 <activity
        android:name="activity_name">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Edit:**
If you have written `<intent-filter>` of your activity as mentioned above then on you can open your app on html button click as follow.

On Click of html page button call a url `http://www.example.com`

example:

```
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://www.example.com'" value='Open App'>
```

Comment: will you please provide some sample code link ...
i spend couple of hours but still no progress.
please help me